# CASE in where clause with Col1<>Col2

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, where-clause

In the following sample data i need to select all records where

1. `ModelOut=ModelOut` (all)
2. `ModelIn<>ModelOut`
3. `ModelIn=ModelOut`

The problem is `ModelIn<>ModelOut` because i don't know how to do it with `CASE` statement in where clause.

```
Declare @type int;
SET @type=2; --- ModelIn <> ModelOut  

Create table #Data(ID int, ModelIn varchar(10), ModelOut varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #Data
    SELECT 1 AS ID,'A' AS ModelIn, 'B' AS ModelOut
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS ID,'B' AS ModelIn, 'B' AS ModelOut
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3 AS ID,'C' AS ModelIn, 'D' AS ModelOut
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4 AS ID,'D' AS ModelIn, 'D' AS ModelOut

SELECT * FROM #Data
WHERE ModelOut =
    CASE  @type
        WHEN 1 THEN ModelOut --- all
        WHEN 2 THEN ???      --- ModelIn <> ModelOut
        WHEN 3 THEN ModelIn  --- ModelOut = ModelIn
    END
;

Drop table #Data;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `CASE` for your query (in fact, it only complicates things here, I'd say). Just write your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM #Data
WHERE (
    @type = 1 OR
   (@type = 2 AND (ModelIn <> ModelOut)) OR
   (@type = 3 AND (ModelOut = ModelIn))
);
```

Comment: nice post but don't you think "or" in query reduce the performance.

Comment: While I haven't done any measurements and can't therefore make any definite statements, I don't think that the OR here really affects performance, for the following reason: the first checked condition always checks against a variable and not a table column, which should be very cheap; considering short-circuit evaluation, this might even be the only condition needing a check; the second condition is basically the same as when using `CASE`, so my guess is that it might even be slightly faster than using a more convoluted case construct. Or is there a general issue with OR and performance?

Answer (score 2):

As a case you can do some trick with one more `CASE`. If `WHERE` clause you've provided is not a simplified variance of a more compelx query - I would use approach suggested by `nyarlathotep` with refactored WHERE clause.

```
 WHERE ModelOut =
        CASE  @type
            WHEN 1 THEN ModelOut --- all
            WHEN 2 THEN 
                       CASE WHEN ModelIn <> ModelOut THEN ModelOut
                            ELSE ModelOut  + '_'
                       END
            WHEN 3 THEN ModelIn  --- ModelOut = ModelIn
        END
```

So when `ModelIn <> ModelOut` - entire CASE would return true, otherwise false

Comment: Actually my sample is simplified but nyarlathotep's approach works still fine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
you should change your select query in this way

Declare @type int;
    SET @type=2; 
    SELECT * FROM #Data
    WHERE (@type = 1 )
    union
    SELECT * FROM #Data
    WHERE  (@type = 2 AND (ModelIn <> ModelOut)) 
      union 
      SELECT * FROM #Data
    WHERE    
          (@type = 3 AND (ModelOut = ModelIn))
```

may be helpfull